Why doesn't my live USB boot partition show up as a 'Linux filesystem'?
I am trying to follow the steps on https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive to recover my system which is currently not booting. I've created and booted a live version of Debian on a USB stick. However when I run fdisk -l from the terminal inside the live system I get the following output:
Disk /dev/sda: 57.62 GiB, 61872793600 bytes, 120845300 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xccc4b779

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       64 6756479 6756416  3.2G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2        6804   16339    9536  4.7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

I expect the Type of /dev/sda1 to be Linux filesystem since that is the root partition but instead it is Empty.
Following the steps in the RescueLive guide further I also run into the following issue when trying to bind mounts of /dev /proc and /sys:
root@debian:~# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount: /mnt/proc: mount point does not exist.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
root@debian:~# mkdir /mnt/proc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/proc’: Read-only file system

When trying to mount, the mount point doesn't exist inside /mnt but I am unable to create it!

Note the Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0. You seem to be looking at the contents of the RescueLive USB, not the system disk you wish rescued. First make sure that the drivers for the appropriate storage controller(s) are loaded: on modern systems, modprobe ahci; modprobe nvme might do the trick in many cases. Then use lsblk or cat /proc/partitions to see what disk devices are available. When booted from a rescue media, the device names might vary from what you're used to - in particular, what you're used to seeing as /dev/sda might be /dev/sdb instead.

OK, these are two different issue. The first issue is that you assume that /dev/sda1 (on your USB key) is a normal file system (say, ext4 or something) on a partition. That doesn't seem to be the case; it's probably a read-only file system image (say, squashfs). Anyways, what is in the partition table as file system type has, for things your computer firmware doesn't interact with, to the best of my knowledge, absolutely no consequence other than for printing in fdisk, so I'd ignore that.
The other issue is that /mnt/ doesn't contain a proc directory, which means you have not (at least not successfully) mounted the original root file system of your installed Linux system on that yet.
You'll have to do that before you can take any other steps. If mounting doesn't work (e.g. due to file system errors), that needs to be addressed – it's pretty likely also the reason why your original system doesn't work.

because the filesystem on your usb stick is invalid;
in the guide you mentioned they showed the output is "Linux filesystem"

but yours in "Empty"

solution: re-format your usb stick partition to ext4 and try again it should work then
